# Azure OpenAPI: Streamed response works on localhost but not on Azure Web App

Tags: next.js, azure-openai

I am using the Fetch API to get a streamed response from my API endpoint. The response works as expected when I test it on my local machine. However, once I have deployed the app to an Azure Web App, I am no longer receiving a streamed response.

Here is the relevant code snippet from my fetch request:

```
const res = await fetch(url, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    ...(OPENAI_API_TYPE === 'openai' && {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${key ? key : process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY}`
    }),
    ...(OPENAI_API_TYPE === 'azure' && {
      'api-key': `${key ? key : process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY}`
    }),
    ...((OPENAI_API_TYPE === 'openai' && OPENAI_ORGANIZATION) && {
      'OpenAI-Organization': OPENAI_ORGANIZATION,
    }),
  },
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    ...(OPENAI_API_TYPE === 'openai' && {model: model.id}),
    messages: [
      {
        role: 'system',
        content: systemPrompt,
      },
      ...messages,
    ],
    max_tokens: 1000,
    temperature: temperature,
    stream: true,
  }),
});
```

Note that the stream parameter is set to true in the body of the request.

When I run this code on localhost, the response is streamed and processed as expected. However, on Azure Web App, the response is received all at once, as if it were not being streamed.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I receive the streamed response on Azure Web App?

Comment: how are you processing the response?  It should use a Readable stream https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream

Comment: @JeremyFiel, yes it is a ReadableStream, and its working as expected on localhost

Answer (score 1):

it might not work for you, but it could help someone else. Thanks

```html
    const stream = new OpenAIStream(response);
    // return new StreamingTextResponse(stream);


    // use this instead of StreamingTextResponse(stream);
    return new Response(stream, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
            'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff'
        }
    });
```

I am sharing full code for the API route.js

```html
// Developed By VarenyaZ Qneus

import OpenAI from 'openai';
import { OpenAIStream, StreamingTextResponse } from 'ai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
export async function POST(req) {
    let { messages } = await req.json();

    const instructions = {
        role: 'system',
        content: `You are a Chatbot. Assist users with correct answers`
    };

    messages = [instructions, ...messages];

    const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
        model: 'gpt-4-1106-preview',
        stream: true,
        messages,
    });

    const stream = new OpenAIStream(response);
    // return new StreamingTextResponse(stream);

    return new Response(stream, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
            'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff'
        }
    });
}
```